# mono of map to flux conversion

Tags: java, java-8, reactive-programming, reactive, spring-data-r2dbc

I want to convert a Mono of map to flux . can anyone help me on that please?

The object that I have is something like

`Mono<Map<Integer , Project>>`

where map key is the project key

From this mono I want to construct a flux of project which is something like

`flux<project>`

as map key is the project id which is present in the project object, we can ignore that.

I try something like this but that did not work I also do not want to use type conversion directly.

```
     Flux<Project> projectFluxReturn = (Flux<Project>) result.toStream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(Project::getProjectId, Function.identity(), (Project project1, Project project2) -> {
                    project1.getTaskList().addAll(project2.getTaskList());
                    project2.getTaskList().clear();
                    return project1;
                })
        )
                .values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`flatMapMany`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-)?

In your code should look like this

```
Flux<Project> projectFluxReturn = result.toStream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Project::getProjectId, Function.identity(), (project1, project2) -> {
            project1.getTaskList().addAll(project2.getTaskList());
            project2.getTaskList().clear();
            return project1;
        }))
        .values()
        .stream()
        //in case you want to flattern the list use .flatMap
        .flatMap(whatever -> Flux.fromIterable(whatever.getWhatever()));
```

### Edit

```
Mono<Map<Integer, Project>> monoMap = result.toStream();
Flux<Project> fluxProject = monoMap.flatMapMany(map -> Flux.fromIterable(map.values()));
```

Comment: Thank a lot for replying  back ...  can you please explain Flux.fromIterable(whatever.getWhatever()) by "getWhatever()" what do you mean?

Comment: In case you want to flattern the thing you have inside `Project`you'll need to do the `flatMap` otherwise just use `.values()`

Comment: if I use .values () only (as i do not want to flatten the Project) this will return me back Collection<Project> not the flux <Project> is not it? am I missing something? @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Comment: my problem is not to flaten the project object , my issue is I have Mono<Map<Integer , Project>> object which I want to convert into flux<project> format.

Comment: @Sujoy can you try my edit?